# Synonyms for "Charge" as it relates to charging devices?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was trying to think of alternatives to 'charging' a phone or ipad or other electric device, but have come up short.  Obviously, the word has multiple meanings but it seems there are few/no alternatives to this particular definition of it.

I've searched [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/charge?s=t), [Powerthesaurus.com](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/charge/synonyms), [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/charge) among others but was unable to find alternatives.

Any suggestions on alternative words for "*Store electrical energy in (a battery or battery-operated device)"*? (Oxford definition)

Comment: Why do you need an alternative word? Is there anything specific you're looking for in this alternate word (e.g. formality)?

Comment: Partially to avoid repeated use in a document, but mostly out of curiosity - is it the only word for this action?

Comment: Recharge, rejuice... I'd say no, you do have other options. But I guess the question is if "recharge" is different enough (or rejuice isn't too informal) to warrant an answer.

Comment: good suggestions, thanks.  Though informal, rejuice is an interesting one that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: @Balaz2ta in many situations in the real world, people use "plug in" ... "Damn I need to plug in my phone again..." or "that new XYZ phone is great with the battery, it seems I never need to plug in" ... so, maybe it helps in some circumstances.

Comment: @Balaz2ta: If this is a technical/formal document, I suggest going with the repetition as it removes ambiguity by using a consistent definition. Only avoid repetitions if it's prose.

Comment: I don't think there is any other term that is reasonably well recognized and not apt to be ambiguous or confusing.

Comment: @Flater: I'd say that in almost *all* contexts it's a mistake to think "I should avoid repeatedly using the same word", ***unless*** you know perfectly well that the first term you used doesn't *exactly* convey the sense you want (but is nevertheless "the best of a bad bunch"). In which case using various other "near synonyms" might help to collect together different connotations of *le mot juste* (which either doesn't exist, or you don't know anyway). I really don't understand why so many people on ELU (and ELL) seem to think randomly using alternatives is somehow "good style". It isn't.

Comment: (Except that in the context of non-native speakers, the "scatter-gun" approach might have the advantage that the audience have more chance of understanding at least *one* of the alternatives! :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this needs a synonym. It's already a single word that means what people expect it to mean. All of the answers so far would feel incredibly out of place in a document, especially when the right word is already used. @FumbleFingers is completely correct.

Comment: Most *mobile* devices are assumed to be "battery-operated". What exact string of words are you trying to replace?

Comment: One might use "replenish".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend still using the word *charge*, but you can add some variety by changing the verb tense and possibly using the noun form. Also mixing up with recharge as suggested in a comment. A few possibilities:

- To *recharge* your device, connect the USB cord
- Ensure it *has been charged* for at least 5 minutes
- *Charging* the device regularly will help
- If the battery fails to *hold a charge*, contact us

This feels like enough variety to me for an instruction manual or technical document.

Comment: If it's not the first time, **recharge** also works.

Answer (score 9):

It's not perfect but in some cases you could use *top up*. This really assumes charging from an only partially drained state, but is used more broadly. For phones it may be a little confusing as "top up" can also apply to credit; any confusion can be minimised with a little context; some other batteries need topping up with water, but again context helps.

Some examples of real-world use:

- [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ianmorris/2018/03/29/no-your-iphone-battery-isnt-being-destroyed-by-wireless-charging/#52d6508117b5).
- [GiffGaff (UK mobile network)](https://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Blog/5-Things-To-Know-About-Charging-Your-Smartphone-amp-Tablet/ba-p/8138314).
- [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/nov/04/why-your-phone-battery-is-rubbish).
- [Nokia Portable Wireless Charging Plate User Guide (via docplayer)](https://docplayer.net/3576197-User-guide-nokia-portable-wireless-charging-plate-dc-50.html). (Manuals from LG and OnePlus also use the term)

After a comment I wondered if this was specific to British English, or at least uncommon in AMerican English. Google initially seemed to confirm that - but Google knows where I am and gives me results biased towards British sites.  DuckDuckGo on the other hand gave me user manuals aimed at users both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: a great suggestion!  as I mention above "plug in" is sort of similar.

Comment: @cobaltduck - that's fascinating (for me, both versions are common)

Comment: @cobaltduck, here in the UK, "top *off*" is rare and when used means to fill back up to 100% (in anticipation of need). I wouldn't suggest it here. "Top *up*" just means to add a bit and is common.

Comment: I'm also in the Midwestern US (grew up in Michigan, now in a plains state by way of California) and I use both *top up* and *top off*. If I had to make a distinction, *top **up*** feels slightly more natural in this context. For me, *top off* is more often adding the finishing touch, rather than adding a bit more of the same to something that's not-quite-empty (though it can also be used that way). That is, you can top off your coffee with a shot of hazelnut or vodka or whipped cream, but you can only top *up* your coffee with more coffee.

Comment: Thanks @1006a. I thought I'd seen it in the US

Comment: @ChrisH As a fellow Brit I always think of "top off" as meaning "finish" or "complete" rather than "refill"" or "replenish". For instance I might order a mug of chocolate in a cafe and have it "topped off with a squirt of cream"

Comment: @BoldBen in my own use that would just be "topped", but yours seems perfectly normal too, andthere seems to be a consensus that "top off" is about some form of completion. In that case putting a bit more in is better served with "top up" though in some places this isn't particularly common

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for something informal, you can use **rejuice**. You might not find this one in dictionaries, but its meaning is clear, since battery power is sometimes called "juice". Here are some examples of it in use:

> That never happened, but I have missed countless events because I'm an idiot and almost never remember to rejuice my battery at night.
>   <sub>[Laughing at My Nightmare](https://books.google.com/books?id=2c1zAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq="rejuice+my"+phone)</sub>

> Frustrated, I searched through the store thinking they must sell (ungodly expensive) battery packs or something to rejuice my phone.
>   <sub>[Electric Addition to WDW Tomorrowland makes Charging Phones a Breeze](https://chipandco.com/electric-addition-wdw-tomorrowland-charging-phones-breeze-191244/)</sub>

> I won't use a Mophie because I find it too heavy, so whenever I need to rejuice my phone on the run, this is my go-to portable charger.
>   <sub>[Mother’s Day ‘Mom Thrive Guide’ With A Giveaway!](https://womenonthefence.com/2015/05/08/mothers-day-mom-thrive-guide-with-a-giveaway/)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest '**energizing**' since the act of 'charging' involves the input of energy. Electrical energy is used to initiate a chemical reaction within the battery.

> 3. transitive. Physics. To increase the energy of (a body or system); (in later use) esp. to impart energy to (matter, esp. a particle); to cause (a particle) to move into a higher energy state.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62083?redirectedFrom=energise#eid)

Answer (score 3):

Replenish.

Which implies that whatever was there before is now less than it was, and needs more of whatever it is to Replenish that whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Though we generally think of **refuel** in terms of the liquid stuff you put it your car, it should equally apply to refueling a fire with wood, or a battery with chemical bonds.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is used in reference to some*one*, how about using ***capacitate***? 
You are making the electronic device capable again; and I know it is a long shot, but capacitors are used to store electrical energy.

Comment: Could you add a link to a dictionary definition of this term, to back up its relevancy for your answer?

Answer (score -2):

how about **to load**, *Elektrische Ladung* is the German equivalent of the physical Electric Charge *Q*.

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange answers should be *definitive*. If this is genuinely a term in current usage, you should link examples or references to demonstrate that fact. I have never heard this usage of *load* before — if someone told me he was *loading* his phone, I would assume it was a reference to downloading content to consume, or possibly to stowing it for transport — but I am happy to be shown to be wrong.